# Docker how can I Establish TCP connection to container on a specific port(8080)?

Tags: sockets, docker, tcp, docker-container, unix-socket

I'm trying to expose a container port by launching the following command :

```
$ docker run -p 8080:8080 --name container1 -d ubuntu /bin/bash -c 'while true;\
do echo Hello $HOSTNAME | nc -l 8080; done;'
```

As a result of `$ docker ps` :

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
9cd601ae9c7a        ubuntu              "/bin/bash -c 'while…"   2 seconds ago       Up 1 second         0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   container1
```

P.S : the container IP address is 172.17.0.2 .
I tried to established (test) from the **host** a TCP connection to **container1** on the 8080 port using

- `$ nc -p 8080 172.17.0.2 8080`
- `$ nc 172.17.0.2 8080`
- `$ exec < /dev/tcp/172.17.0.2/8080`

All what I have got is : **port in use** for the `nc -p ...` and **connection denied** for the rest.

Comment: What version of docker are you running, and what is the value of `$DOCKER_HOST`.

Comment: @BMitch docker version **Docker version 17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6**, my **$DOCKER_HOST** have no value !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `-p 8080:8080` you are mapping the container port `8080` to host port `8080`. Therefore you need to use `nc localhost 8080` to access the container from your host.

BTW: The latest ubuntu image does not contain `nc`. You might want to try `ubuntu:trusty`.

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 --name container1 -d ubuntu:trusty /bin/bash -c 'while true; do echo Hello $HOSTNAME | nc -l 8080; done;'
```

Comment: @Nahdiroviç Which error do you get? Also post `docker logs container1`

Comment: It generate no error, but it doesn't connect, about the **docker logs container1** -> **/bin/bash: nc: command not found**

Comment: @Nahdiroviç your image does not contain `nc`. Try using `ubuntu:trusty`

Comment: you are wright, i tried to install **nc** under the **-c** but it doesn't work for the **ubuntu** image which i was working on. And your solution worked just fine with **ubuntu:trusty**

Comment: @Nahdiroviç great. then you could accept the answer :)